# If $\,A^3-A+I=0,\,$ then $A$ is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

**Prove or disprove.** *If $A$ is a square matrix and $A^3-A+I=0,$ then $A$ is invertible.*

> Is it possible to say the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $\,p(t)=t^3-t+1$, and $A$ is invertible since $0$ is not an eigenvalue of the characteristic polynomial?

Comment: You can't say that exactly, the only thing you can say is that $t^3-t+1$ is divided by the minimal polynomial and therefore $0$ is not a root of the latter. Since the minimal polynomial and the characteristic polynomial have the same roots, $0$ is not an eigenvalue of $A$.

Comment: $A^3-A+I=0 \implies A^2-I+A^{-1}=0$ (assuming $A^{-1}$ exists)$ \implies A^{-1}=I-A^2$ which exists. Therefore $A$ is invertible.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Hint.
$$
A^3-A+I=0\quad\Longrightarrow\quad A(I-A^2)=I.
$$

Answer (score 3):

Call $B= (-1)(A^2 - I)$, now $(-1)(A^2 - I)A=I$ so you have $B$ as one side inverse, on the other side also $A(-1)(A^2-I) =I$.

Answer (score 3):

Check this out:

Since

$A^3 - A+ I = 0, \tag{1}$

we have

$A(I - A^2) = (I - A^2)A = I.  \tag{2}$

(2) shows that

$A^{-1} = I - A^2, \tag{3}$

so $A$ is invertible.

It is not in general true that (1) implies the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $t^3 - t + 1$; if $\text{size}(A) \ne 3$, for example, it cannot be the case, since the degree of the characteristic polynomial is equal to the size of the matrix.
What we *can* say, however, is that every eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$ satisfies

$\lambda^3 - \lambda + 1 = 0, \tag{4}$

for

$Av = \lambda v \tag{5}$

yields

$A^3 v = A^2(Av) = A^2(\lambda v) = \lambda A(Av)$
$= \lambda^2 Av = \lambda^3 v, \tag{6}$

so that

$(\lambda^3 - \lambda + 1)v = (A^3 - A + I)v = 0, \tag{7}$

and since $v \ne 0$ (it is an eigenvector), (4) binds.  Thus no eigenvalue can vanish; again, $A$ is invertible.